# Passed function as parameter isn't called on subscribe

Tags: angular, function, object, subscription

I'm generating a node where I pass function as such:

```
this.navigatinoService.generateNode(null, null... , this.navigationService.displayApkStoreMenu,..)
```

and the generate function looks something like this.

```
public generateNode(translationId: string, iconId: string, display: any, disabled, routerLink: string, children: SideNavNode[]): SideNavNode {
    const node: SideNavNode = {
      translationId: translationId,
      iconId: iconId,
      display: this.userService.getUser().subscribe(() => node.display = display()),
      disabled: disabled,
      routerLink: routerLink,
      children: children
    };

    this.SIDENAV_TREE_DATA.push(node);
    return node;
  }
```

I wan't to be subscribed to the `userService.getUser()` which will trigger when user changes. And when the user changes I want to trigger the display function again to either return true or false.

Here is an explample of the the function displayApkStoreMenu:

```
displayApkStoreMenu(): boolean {
    // some code...
    return // either true or false
  }
```

Right now when the user changes the function isn't called at all and neither does the value of display changes. But I know the subscribe is triggering because when I put `console.log` instead of `node.display = display()` it will trigger the `console.log`.

Comment: Do you have any error in the console when the user changes?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors. I put console.log in the displayApk... function so I know when it triggers but nothing in the console.

Comment: Then are you sure that on the method `getUser()` you are always returning the same observable? Can you show us the code of that method?

Comment: If I put console.log instead of node.display = display() it will log it into the console so I know the subscribe is triggering properly. I don't need the value that getUser returns, I just need it to trigger my function and i know getUser is being triggered properly.

Comment: Can you try and move the line of code `this.userService.getUser().subscribe(() => node.display = display())` to after the object `node` instantiation? I mean, you are trying to apply to the node display property the result of the `displayApkStoreMenu` method but what you are getting is a subscription. Sure, you are overriding it later when the user changes but what if the method is called synchronously? That could happen depending of the content of the `getUser` method. If it does not work, we need a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I'll create stackblitz when I have time a bit later in the day.

Comment: OK well I made some progress but now I have problem that when I call the node.display() to the node.display equals the return value of the function I lost the function because now  the node.display equals the return value so either true or false. Is there a fancy way to resolve this? I thought of one way and that is to have to variables display and function so they don't over and the function var will give value to display but that is not the best solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232648/discussion-between-david-fontes-and-c0mpl3x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem a different way. I didn't even need to execute the function on subscribe, I just passed the value like this:

```
function : () => this.myFunction()
```

and the value will change when the return value of the function changes.
So I guess It's just like subscribing to the value of the function.